# 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django-forms

I am using django framework for the first time. I want to fetch the data from my model course to show it in choice field of form. but when i am using the same model for two diiferent field in single form, it is showing the error **'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'objects'**. here is my code.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class course(models.Model):
    course_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 2)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    stream = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    number_of_sem = models.IntegerField(max_length = 2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.course_id
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from feedback_form.models import course

class loginForm(forms.Form):
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=course.objects.values_list('course_name', flat = True))
    semester = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=course.objects.values('number_of_sem'))
```

Comment: Will you please add stacktrace to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `forms.py`

```
class loginForm(forms.Form):
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=course.objects.values_list('course_name', flat = True))
    semester = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=course.objects.values('number_of_sem'))
```

You have `course` field in `forms.py` when your refer `course` in your `forms.ModelChoiceField` it got confuse about `course` Model and `course` field.

Please change field variable name.

Comment: Can you give full traceback ?